# How to create a debian package of a project that is using a common code base?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, debian, source-packages

current project has a source code which is using the common code from the outside of my project, but i want to create the debian pack of my project. i dont know how to resolve the common source code dependency when i want to create the debian pack. is there any way to create debian pack of just source code and that i can give in my project depends in control file?

example:

$current_directory

my_src/ debian/ CMakeList.txt ...

$cd ../

common_src/

the "my_src" is using the "common_src" code can anyone help me to create the debian pack of this kind of problem.

Comment: The question is needs a bit of clarification, I am afraid.

Comment: @smoe i have a common code base for the RTOS and embedded linux in a source tree. we are using some *.c files in embedde linux project from common code base. when i want to create a debian pack of my embedded linux project how to clear the dependencies of the common code base(i just want to pack the common code(only *.c ,*.h, and some scripts) base without compiling and that debian pack i wanted to use in the embedded linux project as depends when am creating the debian pack. is it possible this way ?)